# Fail2ban regex doesn't match (no sense!)

Tags: regex

Here's a log:

```
[1617620801] [0.0042] [domain.com] [#5006616] [269] [3] [(ip removed)] [403] [GET] [/study/index.php] [SQL injection] [hex:4745543a61203d203b2044524f50205441424c45203c]
[1617621606] [0.00205] [domain.com] [#2926762] [0] [2] [(ip removed)] [403] [POST] [hex:2f786d6c7270632e706870]
```

My regex has the following pattern:

```js
failregex = \[.*] \[.*] \[.*] \[.*] \[.*] \[(3)] \[<HOST>] \[.*] \[.*] \[.*]
```

However, if I change the `\[3]` to `\[2]` it can find the second one. If I change it to `\[.*]` it finds both of them.

Regex testing websites show that it is supposed to work. I have no idea why it doesn't find the `[3]`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it won't wiork due to catastrophic backtracking.

You need to

- Replace all `\[.*]` with `\[[^][]*]`
- In case there can be more than one space between `[...]`, use  `+` or `\s+` instead of literal spaces.

You can use something like

```py
\[[^][]*]\s+\[[^][]*]\s+\[[^][]*]\s+\[[^][]*]\s+\[[^][]*]\s+\[(3)]\s+\[<HOST>]\s+\[[^][]*]\s+\[[^][]*]\s+\[[^][]*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8xDckQ/1).